# Parallel Hint in Delete Statement

Tags: oracle

We have one table which is having 13 million rows. We are doing some calculation and at the end we are trying to delete qty=0 rows (which are actually 5 million rows approx.).

I am using this query:

```
DELETE /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ FROM Table_Name WHERE QTY = 0;
```

This is taking more than 12 minutes to delete those 5 million rows.

Any idea how to reduce that time by using any other options?

Thanks,
TSB

Comment: There is an option to delete in batches , however it may not improve the performance but it may not block the process .  https://rcrdo.com/2023/01/20/how-to-efficiently-delete-millions-of-records-in-a-sql-table/

Comment: I was asking for performance related.

Comment: At nearly a third of your table, replacing the table segment entirely is far, far superior to deleting rows. See cengiz' answer below. If you did do a delete, you'd want to enable parallel dml first or that parallel hint would be ignored. You'd also want to drop indexes first and then rebuild them afterwards.

Comment: @PaulW drooping index is fine, when we create it again having millions of data, it will take same amount of time.

Comment: @TSB, no, recreating/rebuilding the index (which should be done with parallelism) is *much* faster than modifying it in-flight during the delete.

Answer (score 1):

As tested on the Oracle Blog, when it comes to delete lots of records from a table, usual delete from syntax is the slowest.
As explained [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-delete-millions-of-rows-fast-with-sql), I think you can build a structure for that as:

1. Create a new table saving the rows you want to keep
2. Truncate the original table
3. Load the saved rows back in with insert as select

Which means in your case, create a table that holds values

```
create table rows_to_keep
  select * 
  from table_name 
  where  qty != 0;

truncate table table_name;

insert into table_name
select * from rows_to_keep;
```

And even better, you can use swap logic as
The process for this is similar:

1. Create a new table saving the rows you want to keep
2. Drop or rename the original table
3. Rename the new table to the original

```
create table rows_to_keep
  select * from table_name
  where quantity != 0;

rename table_name
  to table_archived;

rename rows_to_keep
  to table_name;
```